# EventEmitter memory leak on running MEAN app on AWS

Tags: node.js, eventemitter

I am working on a MEAN Stack based application and when i try to host the project on AWS then every thing goes properly and when i run the app then  the server started on PORT 80 in command promt. when i try to run the provided ip on browser then it start showing the following error.

```
Possible eventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 listeners added.
use emitter. setmaxListener() to increate the limit.
```

I have tried to set the emitter.setmaxeventListener  but didn't able to resolve the issue.
[image]

Comment: How did you set the maxEventListener, can you provide the setting maxEventListener code?

Comment: actually i didn't know vwhere to set it so i tried to set maxevent emitter in the server.js file but unable to resolve the issue. and i am also unable to find the event.js in which it is showing the errors in command promt.
is it possible that it is coming due to improper installation of mongoose....

Comment: you have to set it on the `emitter` instance. `emitter` instance is the one which we get using `new EventEmitter`. And by default, you can have 10 listeners using `emitter.on`, and have its value more than 10 using maxEventListener if you want to add more. Can you provide the code to get the idea what may be happening